# "Background-image: cover" broken on mobile

Tags: css, background-image, cover

I'm trying to make the image on my site to display 100% height but crop width as needed. On PC the site works as intented as can be seen below:

[image: My site on my PC (Chrome 66.0.3359.117)]

However when I check the site with my phone it displays the whole image distorting it.

[image: My on my phone (Chrome 65.0.3325.109]

HTML:

```
<header class="wide">
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.wide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('sebastian-unrau-42537-unsplash.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .wide {
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: initial;
    }
}
```

The media query is mandatory as the image doesn't work at all if the background-image is fixed and centered.

Now if I remove "background-size: cover":

[image: On mobile without background-size: cover]

It's kind of closer what I'm after but not quite. Am i missing something?

My PC is running Chrome 66.0.3359.117 and my phone 65.0.3325.109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out by accident. I was using an image from [Unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/v4e3JI7DDHI) and the the original resolution is 6000x4000. As I was making a Codepen project to post here I resized the image and wondered why it worked on codepen but not on my pc. Well it seems the resolution needs to be about 5500x3667 or smaller to work.

Maybe there is a limitation I did not know of but anyway got it working now. I didn't change anything else.

[image: Now working on my phone]

Comment: Spot on! Just what i was searching for. I was trying to achieve the exact same thing with large images in a quick mockup project. Everything was working fine  on PC/Mac/iPhone but not my Android device Chrome Browser. Reducing the large image size from 8000x6000px to 2048x1365px did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this property :

```
background-size: x% y%;
```

The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical.

So you can try :

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Unfortunately it doesn't work. Even when I use "auto 100%", it still looks like picture #2.